# move mod_rewrite content from .htaccess to apache2.conf

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

After moving this mod_rewrite code from .htaccess in the directory to apache2.conf its no longer working

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^                   index.php [L,NS]
```

## error

Bad Request

Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put them inside a [Directory](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#directory) block.

> Any directive that you can include in a .htaccess file is better set in a Directory block, as it will have the same effect with better performance.